Запятая перед тире (когда вставная конструкция обособляется двумя тире)
Нужна ли запятая перед вторым тире в предложении:
А если с чем-то и не справится — например, не сможет вернуть человека к жизни(,) — то сядет с тобой и будет нежно гладить по плечу.

Правильно:
А если с чем-то и не справится — например, не сможет вернуть человека к жизни, — то сядет с тобой и будет нежно гладить по плечу.
Розенталь § 26. Вводные и вставные конструкции  »»   Вставные предложения и словосочетания

В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо тире, могут быть еще запятые. Здесь возможны следующие случаи:


перед вторым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура второй части основного предложения или вставной конструкции:

Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — а это с ним изредка происходит, — он пытается стать рационалистом. Вставное предложение примыкает к предшествующей придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, и запятая ставится после всей конструкции;
